# Is there a command to make a Pytest restart?

Tags: python, pytest

I'm running a test which uses two variables which are randomly selected. However, the test only 'works' if the two variables are different. If they are the same, I would like to 'restart' the test.

Essentially I'm trying to do something similar to the following:

```
import random
import pytest

WORDS = ["foo", "bar"]

def test_maybe_recursive():
    word1 = random.choice(WORDS)
    word2 = random.choice(WORDS)

    # Ensure that 'word1' and 'word2' are different
    if word1 == word2:
        print("The two words are the same. Re-running the test...")
        test_maybe_recursive()

    assert word1 != word2       # The actual test, which requires 'word1' and 'word2' to be different

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_maybe_recursive()
    # pytest.main([__file__, "-s"])     # This sometimes fails
```

In this example, I use recursion to ensure that within `test_maybe_recursive`, `word1` and `word2` are different. In the `if __name__ == "__main__"` block, however, if I replace the simple function call with the `pytest.main` call, the test fails (half the time) because the recursion doesn't work.

How can I make the test 'restart' itself so that the example works with Pytest?

Comment: Why do the inputs need to be random?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should address getting a correct setup for the test, rather than trying to add flow control to the test runner.  **Avoid logic in the test code**, because then you are obliged to test the tests.

You could use `random.sample` instead of using `random.choice`:

```
word1, word2 = random.sample(WORDS, 2)
```

Assuming there are no duplicates in `WORDS`, they're guaranteed to be unique choices from the population.

Answer (score 2):

Don't re-call the function, simply have the function generate you some new words:

```
import random
import pytest

WORDS = ["foo", "bar"]

def test_maybe_recursive():
    word1 = random.choice(WORDS)
    word2 = random.choice(WORDS)

    # Ensure that 'word1' and 'word2' are different
    while word1 == word2:
        print("The two words are the same. Re-running the test...")
        word1 = random.choice(WORDS)
        word2 = random.choice(WORDS)

    assert word1 != word2       # The actual test, which requires 'word1' and 'word2' to be different

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_maybe_recursive()
    # pytest.main([__file__, "-s"])     # This sometimes fails
```